# MeteorJS - Why is my collection's insert function only be called once?

Tags: javascript, meteor, insert

I'm populating an app using `MeteorJS` and I've stucked at this problem for days. Let's say my app has a collection named `HistoryItem`. This is how I defined the rules for manipulating this collection:

**history_item.js**

```
HistoryItem.allow({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    console.log('Histoy item allow insert');
    var n = 100000000, m = 10;
    doc.modified = new Date;    
    doc.latitude = Math.round(doc.latitude*n)/n;
    doc.longitude = Math.round(doc.longitude*n)/n;
    doc.noise = Math.round(doc.noise*m)/m;
    var u = Meteor.users.find({ _id: userId }).fetch();
    if (u.length > 0) {
      doc.user = {};
      doc.user.name = u[0].profile.name;
    }

    var ok = doc.owner || doc.noisetube;
    if (ok) {
      LiveUser.upsert({owner: doc.owner}, doc);
    }
    return userId;
  },
  remove: function(userId, doc){
    return true;
  }
});

Meteor.publish('history_item', function (userId) {
  return HistoryItem.find({owner: userId}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
});
```

In the client-side, I have this piece of codes to insert documents into that HistoryItem collection:

**client.js**

```
...
    var cursor;
        while (!cursor){
          cursor = Meteor.subscribe('history_item', Meteor.userId());
        }
        var cursor = HistoryItem.find();
        var count = cursor.count();
        console.log("DEBUG: Enter this point");
        if (count < 100) {
          console.log("1");
          HistoryItem.insert(msg, function(err, res) {});
        }
        else {
          Meteor.call('removeLastHistoryItem', Meteor.userId());
          console.log("2");
          HistoryItem.insert(msg, function(err, res) {});
        }
...
```

The weird thing is that in my browser's console, it logs out the line:
`"DEBUG: Enter this line"` and `"1"` **several times**, but in my server-side console, it only display the line `"History item allow insert"` **once**.

I don't know why is such a strange thing happened and I believed this is the reason why my app isn't behave as what I want.

I've been stucked in this problem for days. So I really, really hope that you guys can help. Thanks & appreciate so much in advanced !

Comment: `err` in `HistoryItem.insert(msg, function(err, res) {})` might reveal what's wrong. And in the code you're showing, `msg` is not defined.

Comment: Also, I'd expect the server not to print "DEBUG"..., "1", or "2".  Those appear to be printed on the client only.  What triggers the call to the code displayed in client.js?  Is it a button click?  Can you determine if whatever is calling the displayed code is not calling it multiple times?